# Accessing hive metastore using jdbc with kerberos keytab

Tags: jdbc, hadoop, hive, kerberos

I am trying to connect to a hive metastore that has been configured to use Kerberos for authentication. This works for me when I am not trying to use a keytab file, i.e. when the program prompts me for my password during the authentication process. When I change the configuration to use a keytab I get a long stacktrace containing among other things this statement:

```
Additional pre-authentication required (25) - Need to use PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP/PA-PK-AS-REQ
```

Can anyone give any advice on what I am doing wrong?

The context of my problem, if that is relevant, is that I want to access the hive metastore from a mapreduce job, and of course, a mapreduce job cannot answer to prompts.

My program looks like this:

```
package com.test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class HiveJDBC {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
      System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","gss-jaas.conf");
      System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.debug","true");
      System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
      System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","krb5.conf");

      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://some.machine:10000/default;principal=hive/some.machine@MY_REALM");

      // Do stuff with the connection
   }
}
```

My gss-jaas.conf file looks like this:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useKeyTab=true
   useTicketCache=false
   principal="my-account@MY_REALM"
   doNotPrompt=true
   keyTab="path-to-my-keytab-file"
   debug=true;
};
```

My krb5.conf file looks like this

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = MY_REALM
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d

[realms]     
 MY_REALM = {
  kdc = some.host:88
  admin_server = another.host
 }
```

My keytab file I have generated with the ktutil program using the following command

```
ktutil: addent -password -p username@MY_REALM -k 1 -e aes256-cts
```

Comment: Actually this post is one of the best "quick start" guide I could find when I started messing with Hive and Kerberos. Thanks for sharing the sample configs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, this error was caused by using the wrong encryption type when issuing the ktutil command. Switching to the correct encryption (I won't mention which we use) solved the problem.