# connect to hive in a secured kerberos authenticated cluster using keytab

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I am using  CDH 5.3.3 and using hive JDBC driver to connect to hive in the secured cluster. I tried to login using keytab using

UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(lprincipal, keytabpath);

I have used the following format for hive url.

jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000;AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=EXAMPLE.COM; KrbHostFQDN=hs2.example.com;KrbServiceName=hive

Sample code :

```
// Authenticating Kerberos principal
System.out.println("Principal Authentication: ");
final String user = "cloudera@CLOUDERA.COM";
final String keyPath = "cloudera.keytab";
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(user, keyPath);
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Url is in the following format:

jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000;AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=EXAMPLE.COM;
KrbHostFQDN=hs2.example.com;KrbServiceName=hive

I get the following exception, I would appreciate if some help is provided in identifying the cause of this issue:

```
com.cloudera.hive.support.exceptions.GeneralException: CONN_KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_GET_TICKETCACHE

javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain Princpal Name for authentication
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForName(Krb5LoginModule.java:800)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:671)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:584)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.inv
```

FOr a differn distribution of cluster, after adding debug, I see the following exception :

```
DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login
DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login commit
DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: using kerberos            user:null
DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: using local user:UnixPrincipal: user66
DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: UGI loginUser:user66 (auth:KERBEROS)
DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction as:user66 (auth:KERBEROS) from:org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport.open(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport: opening transport org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport@1f20a0ab
ERROR org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException:   No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
    at   com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:212)
     at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslClientTransport.java:94)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:253)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport.open(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:156)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:96)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
```

Comment: BTW: your URL is missing a **/** or a **/someDB** after the "host:port" part. Without the slash, Hive JDBC driver will fail to parse the arguments properly (unless that issue is finally solved in your version)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I have edited the url section. please check

Comment: It says it is able to login at loginUserFromKeytab(user, keyPath); but the ticket cache cannot be accessed. I doubt that if this API login can be used for JDBC connections?

Comment: Try to create a "private" ticket with "use cache : no", "use keytab : yes" and provide a valid keytab path. It works. And it's even the only way to have it work on Windows BTW.

Comment: Edit: it works when you bypass the Hadoop API entirely, using raw GSS and JAAS and KRB5 config files.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I am using a linux machine.. and you are saying loginUserFromKeytab(user, keyPath) can be used for JDBC connections without using GSS and JAAS and KRB5 config files? Please  provide an example if possible.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I have added the debug results as well with a different distribution of cluster following the same authentication mechanism. The root cause looks similar. Please check.

Comment: Disclaimer: at some point I tried to use the Hadoop authentication API (class UserGroupInformation etc) but I could never get it to work properly. Too many hard-coded and un-documented things in the way they interact with JDBC and with GSS. And I had requirements to build a solution that could work out of the cluster, with minimal dependencies on the Hadoop libraries. So I switched to a "barebones" approach -- it was difficult but I got it to work. As a result*I cannot really help you with this specific issue with loginUserFromKeytab() method* because I am not familiar with it. Sorry.

Comment: Okay.. I understand and I am feeling the pain now.. Can you provide me any documentation using GSS-JAAS and KRB5 for cluster authentication. 
The problem is always at the datanode.. I should not manually kinit at everynode.. need to find a way!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375372/accessing-hive-metastore-using-jdbc-with-kerberos-keytab?rq=1

Comment: One last warning: stick to OpenJDK if possible; the Oracle/Sun JRE does not allow AES256 encryption for Kerberos by default (!!) so you need to install 2 "unlimited strength crypto" JARs to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the help samson.. I shall try with JAAS as you suggested.

Comment: This will help if your using python to connect [https://stackoverflow.com/a/73239770/18620183](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73239770/18620183)

Answer (score 10):

Beware, mortal: Kerberos is just black magic. It will suck your soul away. Seriously.

Now, there is **very poorly documented** way to activate the GSSAPI trace, that is your **only hope** of zooming on the actual issue (probably a cryptic syntax error in a config file that GSS silently discards by default)

```
-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext
```

The original book of spells is [there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/troubleshooting-security.html).

Comment: Perfect comment. Kerberos is black magic! But truth be told, once you get over the steep learning curve things get easier

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12633984/TestCase_HIVE-6486.java) will help you to connect kerberos enabled(kerberised) hive cluster using keytab.

Since you already have a keytab file in place, you additionally need JAAS Config file, Java Subjects abstraction and Java CallbackHandler for a successfull connection. And of course, dependent libraries (jar files) are required.

HTH.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it is preferred](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259/359284) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-dominated answers can become invalid through [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Answer (score 0):

http://appcrawler.com/wordpress/2015/06/18/examples-of-connecting-to-kerberos-hive-in-jdbc/

have some working examples for JDBC connection to a kerberized Hive.

Good advice from @Samson Scharfrichter on debugging. +1'd

> javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by
>   GSSException:   No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed
>   to find any Kerberos tgt)]
>       at   com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:212)
>        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslClientTransport.java:94)

"GSS initiate failed" + "GSSException:   No valid credentials provided" 
normally means your *client-side* kerberos ticket does not exist or has expired.

Please run klist on client side and copy-paste it here.