# Kerberos "Failed to find any Kerberos Key" with Java 1.7 - Acceptor Credential not recognized

Tags: java, kerberos, keytab

I want to identify a service against an ADS with a keytab. It success with Java 8 but not with Java 6 or Java 7. Both fail with the error `GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos Key)`.

In both cases I use `isInitiator=true`, because it fails if not. As far I can see, Java 8 find in the file as well an initiator credential as a acceptor one:

```
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 70; type: 23
Looking for keys for: HTTP/server.firm.com@FIRM.COM
Added key: 23version: 3
KdcAccessibility: reset
Looking for keys for: HTTP/server.firm.com@FIRM.COM
Added key: 23version: 3
...
Search Subject for Kerberos V5 INIT cred (HTTP/server.firm.com@FIRM.COM sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential)
Found ticket for HTTP/server.firm.com@FIRM.COM to go to krbtgt/FIRM.COM@FIRM.COM expiring on Fri Aug 28 19:21:38 CEST 2015
Search Subject for Kerberos V5 ACCEPT cred (HTTP/server.firm.com@FIRM.COM, sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5AcceptCredential)
Found ticket for HTTP/server.firm.com@FIRM.COM to go to krbtgt/FIRM.COM@FIRM.COM expiring on Fri Aug 28 19:21:38 CEST 2015
```

Older java implementations find only the initiator one and generate an exception when they want use an acceptor one:

```
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 70; type: 23
Added key: 23version: 3

Search Subject for Kerberos V5 INIT cred (HTTP/server.firm.com@FIRM.COM, sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential)
Found ticket for HTTP/server.firm.com@FIRM.COM to go to krbtgt/FIRM.COM@FIRM.COM expiring on Fri Aug 28 19:20:35 CEST 2015
Search Subject for Kerberos V5 ACCEPT cred (HTTP/server.firm.com@FIRM.COM, sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5AcceptCredential)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos Key)
    at test.KerberosTicketRetriever$TicketCreatorAction.run(KerberosTicketRetriever.java:97)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:454)
    at ff.support.kerberos.KerberosTicketRetriever.retrieveTicket(KerberosTicketRetriever.java:223)
    at ff.support.kerberos.KerberosTicketRetriever.main(KerberosTicketRetriever.java:292)
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos Key)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5AcceptCredential.getInstance(Krb5AcceptCredential.java:95)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:111)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getCredentialElement(GSSManagerImpl.java:178)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSCredentialImpl.add(GSSCredentialImpl.java:422)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSCredentialImpl.<init>(GSSCredentialImpl.java:42)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.createCredential(GSSManagerImpl.java:139)
    at ff.support.kerberos.KerberosTicketRetriever$TicketCreatorAction.createTicket(KerberosTicketRetriever.java:116)
    at ff.support.kerberos.KerberosTicketRetriever$TicketCreatorAction.run(KerberosTicketRetriever.java:93)
    ... 4 more
```

The keytab itself contains only one key:

```
C:\> jdk\bin\klist -K -e -t -k myFile.keytab
Key tab: myFile.keytab, 1 entry found.
[1] Service principal: HTTP/server.firm.com@FIRM.COM
         KVNO: 3
         Key type: 23
         Key: 0x2e6a4379b2ba26385d687a5e9d3bc6d
         Time stamp: Jan 01, 1970 01:00
```

I not really understand when a keytab is an initiator and when not and why different versions of java lead to different results. Can somebody help?

Comment: Sorry to go back to basics, but... did you run your tests with OpenJDK, Sun/Oracle JVM, something else? In the case of Sun/Oracle, did you download the "unlimited strength" crypto policy JARs *(thanks to an obsolete US export regulation, AES256 was not enabled by default)*?

Comment: BTW there is a trace flag that might prove useful, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31824149/connect-to-hive-in-a-secured-kerberos-authenticated-cluster-using-keytab/31867025#31867025