# Hive client connection using kerberos keytab

Tags: java, hive, kerberos

Using a jdbc connection to hive I can't seem to get hive to actually find the keytab I want to connect with. I've written a custom krb5 login module and to point to the keytab and added it in the java options (-Djava.security.auth.login.config).  Any thoughts on why it might not be taking?

Comment: Activate the GSSAPI trace, only way to debug obscure config issues => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31824149/connect-to-hive-in-a-secured-kerberos-authenticated-cluster-using-keytab/31867025#31867025

Comment: Note that different versions of different JVMs on different platforms may have different syntax requirements (e.g. using a local path such as `./wtf.keytab` will fail in some cases while `wtf.keytab` or `/a/b/wtf.keytab` will always work). Same for double quotes or no quotes. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Before try to establish the connection program, mush ensure that the keytab authentication renewed or not.

Check klist command in linux and check the expired date and time. If the auth. already expired, use kinit command to renew it before establish connection through jdbc.