# Kafka: Send Messages to kerberized cluster from Windows machine

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos

I am working on a scenario where my kafka producer code will reside on a windows machine & my kafka borker is kerberized in a unix machine. Both of the machines are within the same domain. The firewall ports are open between windows & unix machine.

Need help in getting to know how to proceed on this problem.

I went through following questions:
[How to Access kafka brokers secured by kerberos from Eclispe running on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637329/how-to-access-kafka-brokers-secured-by-kerberos-from-eclispe-running-on-windows)
[Connect to Kafka on Unix from Windows with Kerberos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312403/connect-to-kafka-on-unix-from-windows-with-kerberos)

However, none of them have been concluded successfully.