# How to connect a remote Hive server from Python using JDBC and SSL?

Tags: python, hadoop, jdbc, hive, ssl-certificate

I have below Hive client details which require an SSL connection to access the database

```
client_url="jdbc:hive2://myhiveserver.india.mycompany.com:9029/default;ssl=true;transportMode=http;httpPath=gateway/default/hive;trustStorePassword=selfsign"
certificate=mycertficate.pem
```

So which is the right approach to access Hive using JDBC and SSL in Python? I don't see right example for accessing Hive with attaching SSL certificate in my case?

Answer (score 0):

using jaydebeapi and jpype worked for me.
below files need to be added to jvm

1. krb5.config file - your admin will be able to provide this
2. keytab file - for user trying to access hive
3. jaas file - (sample mentioned below)

code:

```
    jaas = './config/jass.conf'
    krb5 = './config/krb5.conf'
    keytab = './config/<userid>.keytab'
    jar = './jars/HiveJDBC41.jar'
    principal = "<host>@<domain>"
    jdbc_url = "jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/default;KrbRealm=<domain>;AuthMech=1;KrbHostFQDN=<host>;KrbServiceName=hive;principal=<host>@<domain>;ssl=1;"

    jvm_path = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
    jpype.startJVM(jvm_path, 
    '-Djava.class.path='+ jar,
    '-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true',
    '-Djava.security.krb5.conf='+krb5,
    '-Djava.security.auth.login.config='+jaas,
    '-Djava.security.auth.login.config.keyTabFile='+keytab,
    '-Djava.security.auth.login.config.principal='+ principal,
    '-Dhadoop.security.authentication="kerberos"', 
    )
    conn = jaydebeapi.connect("com.cloudera.hive.jdbc41.HS2Driver", jdbc_url)
```

jaas file:

```
    Client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useTicketCache=true
    doNotPrompt=true
    useKeyTab=true
    principal="<host>@<domain>"   
    debug=true
    keyTab="./config/<userid>.keytab";
    };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).