# Kerberos java to hive keytab authentication, login failure UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab

Tags: authentication, hive, kerberos, metastore, keytab

I am trying to get kerberos keytab authentication work from java to Hive and not finding solution to fix the issue.

```
    org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new   
       org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
    conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
    conf.set(HiveClientFactory.HIVE_METASTORE_URIS,"thrift://{URL}");
    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
    UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(krbPrincipal, keyTabPath);
```

> java.io.IOException: Login failure for {krbPrincipal} from keytab
>   {keyTabPath}  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:855)
>
> Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain
>   password from user
>
> at
>   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:789)
>     at
>   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:654)

I would really appreciate some insight to help resolve this.

Comment: Your question is about HDFS Kerberos authentication, but the code sample (and maybe the error message) is about Hive Metastore Kerberos authentication. Please remember that Oozie uses a specific "HCat credential" section for Metastore authentication...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, corrected the question and oozie's Hive action has been working with HCat credential, however oozie's Java action - java class internally calls Hive using Hive_Metastore (please refer code snippet from the question) and its failing with error java.io.IOException: Login failure for {krbPrincipal} from keytab {keyTabPath}

Comment: OK, now I get it. You try to connect to either Metastore (Thrift service) or HiveServer2 (Thrift again) using Hadoop authentication mechanism. AFAIK it does not work because Thrift client invokes **directly** the low-level JAAS/GSSAPI authentication libs. In other words it appears to be Kerberos compliant, but not Hadoop aware.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375372/accessing-hive-metastore-using-jdbc-with-kerberos-keytab?rq=1 for a "quick start" guide to raw Kerberos config. Also the discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31824149/connect-to-hive-in-a-secured-kerberos-authenticated-cluster-using-keytab/ (especially the trace flag...)