# HTTPClient login from keytab to access hadoop jobhistory service

Tags: security, hadoop, httpclient, kerberos, keytab

I'm writing a java program to access hadoop jobhistory service to retrieve some information.

I'm using HTTPClient to make the HttpGet call. I need to login from a keytab file (I have the file on my ~/.ssh/ folder) instead of type in user name and password.

My question is: How to login from keytab in HTTPClient?

Here is how I set up my HTTPClient

```
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "krb5.conf");
System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");

System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", prop.getProperty("krb5.realm"));
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", prop.getProperty("krb5.kdc"));

PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
cm.setMaxTotal(200);
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(100);

//TODO login from keytab ?
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("DUMMY", null));

Lookup<AuthSchemeProvider> authRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeProvider>create()
  .register(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, new SPNegoSchemeFactory())
  .build();

httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
  .setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authRegistry)
  .setConnectionManager(cm)
  .build();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

One interesting is this code can run successfully in my IntelliJ. But After I build and run it from command line, it will show up the info to ask me for username and password.

I'm new to authentication, hope somebody can help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375372/accessing-hive-metastore-using-jdbc-with-kerberos-keytab -- no HTTP involved in that case but the GSSAPI config for obtaining the Kerberos ticket is the same. And that trace flag can prove helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31824149/connect-to-hive-in-a-secured-kerberos-authenticated-cluster-using-keytab/31867025#31867025

Answer (score 2):

```
    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    Lookup<AuthSchemeProvider> authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeProvider>create()
            .register(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, new SPNegoSchemeFactory(true)).build();
    builder.setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry);
    BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, -1, null), new Credentials() {
        @Override
        public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
            return null;
        }
    });
    builder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
    final HttpClient httpClient = builder.build();

    final Subject subj = new Subject();
    Krb5LoginModule krb5 = new Krb5LoginModule();

    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("doNotPrompt", "true");
    options.put("storeKey", "true");
    options.put("useKeyTab", "true");
    options.put("useTicketCache", "true");
    options.put("keyTab", keytabFilePath); //Path to keytab file
    options.put("principal", principal);   //Principal name
    options.put("debug", "true");

    krb5.initialize(subj, null, null, options);

    krb5.login();
    krb5.commit();

    HttpResponse response = Subject.doAs(subj, new PrivilegedExceptionAction<HttpResponse>() {
        @Override
        public HttpResponse run() throws Exception {
            return httpClient.execute(request);
        }
    });
```

Comment: adding some details might be nice for others.

Comment: What kind of details do you mean?

Comment: its just a bunch of code ,add some reasons/comments for your code.