# GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-security-kerberos

I am very much new to the MOngoDB + Java Configuration. I am trying to achive the connection from remote mongodb server from Java application. I want to use GSSAPI mechanism for connection with mongotemplate. Below code has been executing successfully. Below code is from my configuration file.

```
List<ServerAddress> serverAddresses = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
    ServerAddress address = new ServerAddress(host, port);
    serverAddresses.add(address);
    List<MongoCredential> credentials = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();

    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createGSSAPICredential(userName);

    credential.withMechanismProperty("SERVICE_NAME", gssapiServiceName);
    credential.withMechanismProperty("CANONICALIZE_HOST_NAME", true);
    credentials.add(credential);

    return new MongoClient(serverAddresses, credentials);
```

But when I am trying execute below code I am getting exception

```
DB db = mongoTemplate.getDb();
Set<String> dbCollections1 = db.getCollectionNames();
```

Exception:

> GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
>       at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
>       at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
>       at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getCredentialElement(GSSManagerImpl.java:193)
>       at sun.security.jgss.GSSCredentialImpl.add(GSSCredentialImpl.java:427)
>       at sun.security.jgss.GSSCredentialImpl.(GSSCredentialImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.createCredential(GSSManagerImpl.java:154)
>       at com.mongodb.DBPort$GSSAPIAuthenticator.getGSSCredential(DBPort.java:622)
>       at com.mongodb.DBPort$GSSAPIAuthenticator.createSaslClient(DBPort.java:593)
>       at com.mongodb.DBPort$SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(DBPort.java:895)
>       at com.mongodb.DBPort.authenticate(DBPort.java:432)
>       at com.mongodb.DBPort.checkAuth(DBPort.java:443)
>       at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:289)
>       at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:269)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:84)
>       at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:320)
>       at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:299)
>       at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:388)
>       at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer.getCollectionNames(DBApiLayer.java:152)

Comment: I don't know anything about MongoDB, but that error message means that GSSAPI thinks you want to use Kerberos protocol -- is that true? if yes, did you provide the config to tell GSSAPI how to contact the Kerberos server? and *(a)* where the existing Kerberos ticket is cached, or *(b)* how to find the password and create the ticket on the fly? By the way, if you use a Sun/Oracle JVM, did you download the "unlimited strength crypto" policy JARs to enable AES256 encryption?

Comment: Yes, I want to use Kerberos protocol. I have set two System Environment Variables 1. KRB5_CONFIG=krb5.conf    2.KRB5_KTNAME=username.keytab    This is what I did for configuration perspective. I am accessing this mongodb server from Java web application. Hope I am able to provide answer to your queries.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375372/accessing-hive-metastore-using-jdbc-with-kerberos-keytab for the dirty details of setting the Kerberos conf (well, some of the details)

Comment: Plus a useful trace flag to untangle config issues: `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext`

Answer (score 19):

Million thanks to all who have responded and take a look to my question.

After adding some System Properties and a new conf file, Finally I am able to get connected with MongoDB server. Herewith the updated code -

```
try {
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","C:/mongodb/UnixKeytab/krb5.conf");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm","EXAMPLE.COM");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc","example.com");
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","C:/mongodb/UnixKeytab/gss-jaas.conf");


        List<ServerAddress> serverAddresses = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
        ServerAddress address = new ServerAddress(host, port);
        serverAddresses.add(address);
        List<MongoCredential> credentials = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createGSSAPICredential(username);
        credentials.add(credential);
        MongoClient mongoClient1 = new MongoClient(serverAddresses, credentials);
        DB db = mongoClient1.getDB(database);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My krb5.conf file look like below -

```
[libdefaults]
     default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
     default_tkt_enctypes = des-cbc-md5 rc4-hmac
     default_tgs_enctypes = des-cbc-md5 rc4-hmac
     default_keytab_name = <keytab file path>
[realms]
EXAMPLE.COM = {
    kdc = example.com
    master_kdc = example.com
    default_domain = EXAMPLE.COM
}
INTRANET = {
    kdc = example.com
    master_kdc = example.com
    default_domain = example.com
}
```

My gss-jaas.conf look like below -

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=true
useTicketCache=false
principal="my-account@MY_REALM"
doNotPrompt=true
keyTab="path-to-my-keytab-file"
debug=true;};
```

Code I have posted is working for me. Hope this will work for others.

Answer (score 6):

Adding some information to this post as its extremely useful already.

If the `Sasl/createSaslClient` is not run within the `Subject:doAs` method
that is retrieved from the `LoginContext`, the credentials will not be picked up from the `krb5.conf` file. I.e the `GSS` code looks at the **current thread's security manager for the Subject** which is registered via the `Subject:doAs` method, and then uses the credentials from this subject. This `Subject` should've been obtained via `jaas` which in turn would read the correct `jaas` and `krb5.conf` credentials, but if you do not run the `sasl` and `saslclient` methods inside the `Subject:doAs` method all this doesn't matter.

You can get around it by setting `javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false` which means if no credentials can be found, some default names in the jaas file will be searched for see [LoginConfigImpl.java#92](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/jgss/LoginConfigImpl.java#92), one is `com.sun.security.jgss.initiate`.

e.g

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate{
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   doNotPrompt=true
   useTicketCache=true
   useKeyTab=true
   keyTab="mykeytab"
   principal="service/host@REALM";
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error "Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt". My problem looks different from yours, but it could be useful to other ones with the same error.

In my case it was caused by an error in writing the principal name in one of my configuration files.

I suggest to check the Jaas LoginManager configuration file (provided with java.security.auth.login.config) and policy files for principals. Typical error is the domain name in lowercase: gino@authdemo.it instead of gino@AUTHDEMO.IT

In the case you set/refer to the principal programmatically, you can also check the principal name correctness in your code.
Regards